# Is there an automatic parallel prolog implementation?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, prolog, logic

I'm currently doing some research in theoretical computer science, and one of the main tools I'm using is prolog. I've found it particularly handy for writing very quick tests to disprove conjectures.

However, I've gotten to a point where the brute-force search is getting too slow. While I could use a different language, the whole point of my using prolog is that it's extremely fast/simple to write code to test a hypothesis.

I'm wondering, is there an implementation of Prolog that allows for automatic paralellization? It wouldn't have to be razor fast, but ideally I'm looking for something that I could just drop my code into and get at least a small speedup.

I don't know if this is possible. Google search reveals lots of academic articles about automatic parallelism in Prolog, but I didn't come across any implementations. However, I'm really only familiar with SWI-prolog, so I could definitely use advice from someone familiar with many implementations.

My code uses cuts, but I am fairly sure that I can eliminate them. As for IO, the only IO is printing to the console, which could probably be moved outside any parallel code.

Comment: I'm familiar with several Prolog implementations, and I've done some projects that involve dividing a search space up into pieces so the work can be spread out over multiple machines.  However I don't know of any drop-and-go implementations.  One view of the failure of Japan's Fifth Generation Computer Systems is that concurrency and logic programming are a poor match.  The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_generation_computer#Failure) mentions this and links to [this arXiv.org paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0904.3036).

Comment: See also [Logic Programming and Concurrency: a Personal Perspective](http://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/projects/ALP/newsletter/may06/nav/articles/ueda/article.html) by Kazunori Ueda, which seems to me a fairly optimistic view.

Comment: I remember reading about "and-parallel" and "or-parallel" Prolog variants, but I don't know if any of that made it into modern production Prolog environments.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly my problem. I've read about the different variants, just haven't been able to find much outside of academic papers and theoretical discussions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Prolog it is not difficult to find parallelism, it is difficult to choose which one to use ;) .

Maybe [Parlog - logic based programming language, designed for parallel execution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parlog) would be of help to you. There is [implementation for windows](http://www.parlog.com/en/parlog.html) but I am not sure if it uses multiple cores. You could however try to contact the authors there.

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure you need parallelism to "get at least a small speedup"?

You say that you are only familiar with SWI-Prolog, so try other Prolog systems. According to the results of a benchmark at http://www.probp.com/performance.htm (which may or may not be relevant to your particular problem) you should try B-Prolog, YAP and SICStus-Prolog (this one is not free). If you're lucky, you can get several times speedup just from switching your Prolog system.

Another possible low-cost way to speed up - use a system with tabling support (B-Prolog, XSB or YAP) and just add something like `:- auto_table.` as a first line of your program. Depending on your problem and your existing program you can get significant speedup (or get no speedup at all).

Comment: +1 for trying other compilers.  Gnu-Prolog in particular compiles to native code, which is almost sure to give noticeable speed-up over SWI-Prolog.

Answer (score 1):

In Jekejeke Prolog I have tried to make it as simple as possible
for a programmer and did offer a simple construct called balance/1. 
With balance/1 a generate and test problem:

```
 /* sequential */
 ?- Generate, Test.
```

Will be distributed over multiple threads. The invokation is as
simple as wrapping the conjunction into the predicate balance/1.
The result might undergo some reordering:

```
 ?- use_module(library(runtime/distributed)).

 /* parallel */
 ?- balance((Generate, Test)).
```

Here is an example parallel generation of prime numbers. The 
sequential code reads as follows:

```
:- use_module(library(advanced/arith)).

prime(N) :-
    M is floor(sqrt(N)),
    between(2,M,K),
    N mod K =:= 0, !, fail.
prime(_).

?- time(aggregate_all(count, 
                     (between(1,1000000,X), prime(X)), N)).
% Up 6,737 ms, GC 33 ms, Thread Cpu 6,656 ms (Current 07/16/19 01:49:02)
N = 78499
```

Doing the same in parallel gives:

```
?- time(aggregate_all(count, 
                      balance((between(1,1000000,X), prime(X))), N)).
% Up 4,167 ms, GC 39 ms, Thread Cpu 219 ms (Current 07/16/19 01:49:50) 
N = 78499
```

So there was a speed-up, since the problem could be run on multiple threads.