# Parallel Primes in Prolog?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, prolog

I have the following simple code to determine prime numbers. Its a simple generate and test, not extremly optimized:

```
prime(N) :-
    M is floor(sqrt(N)),
    between(2,M,K),
    N mod K =:= 0, !, fail.
prime(_).
```

Here is an example run:

```
?- between(1,20,N), prime(N), write(N), nl, fail; true.
1
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
true.
```

How would I parallelize the listing of primes over multiple threads in Prolog? The output listing need not be sorted.

Comment: You want to compute them in parallel? Not sure what you mean by listing them in parallel.

Comment: @j4nbur53: divide the set of input numbers in M disjoint sets where M is the number of parallel threads, and then run each thread with one of the sets

Comment: Of interest: [Parallel Prime Sieve: Finding Prime Numbers](http://www.massey.ac.nz/~mjjohnso/notes/59735/seminars/01077635.pdf)

Comment: Cross [posted](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/thinking-in-prolog-for-procedural-programmers/954/10) at [SWI Prolog Discourse](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/). An answer was given.

Comment: @gusbro disjoint sets is difficult, a lower range can contain more prime numbers than an upper range. You would need to split it uneventy to get the best result. So I decided to use bouqets of 1000 numbers instead.

Comment: @j4nbur53: I didn't say the sets should be of contiguous numbers.

Comment: The below solution will dynamically assign bouquets to threads, depending which thread is starving. Since this is adaptive you don't know in advanced which discontiguous set of numbers is processed in total by which thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could do so far. I deployed JDK 13.0 which is worse in sequential, but better in parallel. I use the [balance/1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57044280/502187) predicate, but apply also some code transformation.

The code transformation is such that I slice the range into bouquets with 1000 numbers, and already do a aggregation. Testing was carried out on a i7-6700HQ which has 8 logical CPUs:

Sequential:

```
Jekejeke Prolog 4, Runtime Library 1.4.0 (July 6, 2019)

?- time(count(N)).
% Up 8,655 ms, GC 39 ms, Thread Cpu 8,593 ms (Current 07/16/19 16:47:49)
N = 78499
```

Parallel:

```
?- time(count2(N)).
% Up 2,628 ms, GC 4 ms, Thread Cpu 0 ms (Current 07/16/19 16:48:16)
N = 78499
```

This is the source code:

```
:- use_module(library(advanced/arith)).
:- use_module(library(advanced/aggregate)).
:- use_module(library(runtime/distributed)).

prime(N) :-
    M is floor(sqrt(N)),
    between(2, M, K),
    N mod K =:= 0, !, fail.
prime(_).

/* sequential */
count(N) :-
   aggregate_all(sum(M), (between(1, 1000, Y), slice(Y, M)), N).

/* parallel */
count2(N) :-
   aggregate_all(sum(M), balance((between(1, 1000, Y), slice(Y, M))), N).

slice(Y, M) :-
   aggregate_all(count, (H is Y*1000, L is H-999, between(L, H, X), prime(X)), M).
```

**Edit 17.07.2019:**
Changed the time/1 predicate so that it also shows the thread CPU time spent in all spawned threads. It seems that the solution is near optimal, since it has a logical CPU utilization which is close to the number of logical CPUs.

Here are some ratios Thread-Time/Up-Time:

```
/* parallel, primes 1, no bouquets */
25622/5732 ~ 4.46 

/* parallel, primes 2, bouquets */
21464/2717 ~ 7.89
```

So I guess the bouquets solution presented here, which does not have very short lived jobs in a high number causes less friction in the distribution framework than the solution with no bouquets.